# Operator does not Converge to Identity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, operators
\begin{align*}
T_k :L^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})
\end{align*}

defined by $(T_kf)(x)=f\left( x+\frac{1}{k} \right)$. I want to prove $\|T_k-I\|$ does not tend to zero while for any $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}), T_kf \rightarrow f$ strongly. I have proved that $T_k f \rightarrow f$ strongly but I am not able yet to prove $\|T_k-I\|$ does not converge to $0$. Any suggestion to prove $\sup \limits_{\|f\|_2 \leq 1} \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f\left( x+\frac{1}{k} \right)-f(x)|^2dx$ does not converge to $0$?

Comment: Consider any function $f$ whose $L^2$ is $1$, but is identically zero outside $[0,\frac{1}{k}]$. What can you say about $\|T_k(f)-f\|$?

Comment: @Giafazio ah, thanks for the hint. So I can take the sequence $(f_n)=n^{1/2}\chi_{[0,1/n]}$ and for $n$ large enough, compare to $k$ we have the integral does not tend to $0$. Is it correct?